# Intellij diagnosing crash problem

Tags: java, crash, intellij-idea, memory-management

Sometimes `Intellij IDEA` crashes for no obvious reason.

First, it becomes quite slow, `CTRL + N` (class search) often takes a bit longer than usual time to respond when you type something into it, jumping between files takes more time. And then it crashes..

What is the usual route to diagnose `Intellij` crash? I've been monitoring memory on the status bar when it crashed and it had about 100MB (out of 512MB) left at that time. Are there any useful logs that would point in the direction of the problem?

[UPDATE] 3 crashes in total.

1 instance:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
>  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d93acab, pid=3120, tid=5588
>
>  JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
>  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
>  Problematic frame:
>  V  [jvm.dll+0x9acab]

2 instances:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 32756 bytes for ChunkPool::allocate. Out of swap space?
> Internal Error (allocation.cpp:166), pid=2484, tid=5568
> Error: ChunkPool::allocate

Memory configuration:
-Xss2m
-Xms32m
-Xmx512m

Increased the memory to `-Xmx768`, hopefully that will delay the out of memory error by a bit. Increasing the memory to `-Xmx1024` caused weird address mapping problems after running IDEA for a while (integer overflow?). The machine has 3GB of RAM.

Comment: The location of the log files is system-dependent but it will be something like ~UserHomeDir/.IdeaXXX/system/log.  Maybe if you update your question with a relevant part someone will have a chance of answering it.

Comment: I can see lots of memory exceptions in there, there are like 20 MB of logs. I can't say exactly what was the last exception when it crashed, will try increasing jvm memory and if/when that happens again look at the last few logs. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please define "crashes". If the window just disappears, it usually means the JVM bug and there will be **hs_err_pidXXX.log** files in the IDEA working directory (usually IDEA_HOME/bin). In some cases updating JDK to the new version or changing Garbage Collector strategy (via vmoptions file) can workaround such issues.

If the IDE stops responding completely, you need to [provide thread dumps](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348667).

If it behaves weird, then you need to check **idea.log** for exceptions. In some cases it can be caused by OutOfMemory issues. Increasing heap size in idea.vmoptions should help. [Check the FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) for IDEA files locations.

If IDEA is becoming very slow on certain operations, you need to [provide CPU snapshot](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-192).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that helped to find the logs of the crash. And other details are helpful as well. In my case the window just disappeared. I've updated the answer with more details, and it seems that in 2 out of 3 instances the error was caused by the memory problem.

Comment: Such issues can be caused by memory fragmentation. 768m should be the safe value but going upper can cause problems when running under 32-bit JVM.

Answer (score 14):

Intellij wouldnt start up i.e. flashes IntelliJ and crashes.

**Fix:** Set -Xmx to default 512MB in `idea.exe.vmoptions` file located in folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.1.4\bin`

**How I landed on this issue:** I was having Xmx set to 2048MB earlier and it crashed hitting GC limit. Then on IntelliJ wouldn't start.

Comment: Is there a way to go above this limit without it crashing? I'm hitting the same problem after I've modified the memory allocation.

Comment: Yeah it was the issue in my case.

Comment: This is really counter-intuitive. Are you saying that if I'm running out of memory, I should reduce the memory allocated to the JVM?

Comment: In my case I needed to modify `idea.exe.vmoptions` located in `c:\Users\<user name>\.IntelliJIdea14\`  It seems that `idea.exe.vmoptions` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition ...\bin` is only used as a template or something.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answer, I added:

`-Dswing.noxp=true` to .vmoptions file located at IDE_HOME\bin\[bits][.exe].vmoptions

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: What does this particular parameter does...it resolved my intellij crashing issue but I want to know the reason for that.